# STM32 input "source" current

Tags: voltage, stm32, input

I am working on a kind of voltage meter which will be able to measure positive and negative voltages and will have 2 ranges connected to 2 separate pins of STM32. My problem is that at the most negative voltage being measured, the voltage applied to the lower range pin on the STM32 will be negative (at this point the MCU will be measuring only the higher range input). Of course I understand that the lowest allowed voltage on an input pin is Vss-0.3V. However, this assumes connecting a voltage source with low output impedance. My question is: can I connect e.g. -3V through a 1k resistor to the STM32 input? There is no such thing as maximum "input source" current. I guess I could probably design it differently to avoid this problem but this would be a convenient solution and I am curious about it.

Comment: You could do as you describe, but the outcome would be no different - the input will be clamped at Vss-0.3V. If you want to measure negative voltages then shift or bias the input to an acceptable voltage range.

Comment: Which STM32? They all have their own datasheet with their own values.

Comment: @Kartman I understand. At this point that input will be unused and I will not attempt to measure it. I only care about whether it will be damaged or not. Is maximum "input source" current defined somewhere?  MCU is STM32F767.

Comment: It’s a bad idea to exceed to chip specs. Strange things may happen if you do.

Comment: @Rafal yes the currents that are the absolute maximum rating (means may not work but no immediate damage) and also the recommended maximum ratings are in the datasheet electrical specifications section.

Comment: @Rafal Each I/O pin can sink/source up to max. 25mA/-25mA. But that doesn't mean that you should go below the rated voltage specs.

Comment: @Seir that applies only when the pin is an output, it can source or sink a good amount of current. But in this case the pin is an input and below 0V so you need to look at injection current, which may be 5mA or not allowed depending on pin, and for ADC use it is really sensitive.

Comment: @Justme Thanks, I didn't know that. I'll dig a little further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some pins tolerate 5mA negative injection (clamp current). Some pins don't. Voltage can go 0.3V negative.

Putting a 1k resistor to -3V would only mean approximately 2.7mA would flow, but any circuit that is designed to operate intentionally and constantly through internal protection structures is just a poor design.

Comment: Thanks. I guess probably it is better to think about different solution.

Answer (score 2):

MCU pins have **source and sink current specs**, which you can find in datasheet of the specific MCU.

If you connect it the way you want, I don't think anything good will come out of it, because when you make GPIO output LOW on some pin (0V), you effectively turn on an N-MOSFET from that pin to GND. So if you connect -3V even via 1k, I'm not sure it's within the spec. You will source the current from GND to -3V through the pin through the body diode of that N-channel MOSFET. Given it's a small current - 3mA, it will probably live, but it's not intended that way. And not really necessary.

Also, -0.3V lowest voltage simply means that it works from the lowest rail of 0V, it can tolerate a little bit fluctuation. Every chip that is powered from some Vcc and GND has most negative absolute maximum of -0.3V, literally take almost any common single supply IC and that -0.3V is there in the absolute maximum ratings.

If you want to measure negative voltages, you will have to bias them (shift them) up. For example, you can turn -3V into 0V and -2V into 1V and so on (everything +3V). Of course, if there is a wider range of voltages than 3.3V, you can also scale it.

Example:

You want to measure voltages from -10V to 0V. So you shift it up by 10V (becomes 0V to 10V). And then you scale it down to 0V to 3V, for instance, with voltage divider. And this you feed into MCU. So you effectively have 2 MCU pins with ADC. One reads positive voltages scaled by voltage divider to fit into 3.3V, another one reads shifted and then scaled voltages.

Make sure the voltage applied to MCU pins will not exceed the specs of MCU. You may want clamp zener diodes on input (3.6V for example or better 3.3V, but then your max should be around 3.0V because zener will start to leak closer to 3.3V and ruin the measurement) just in case.

Comment: Thanks. I understand idea of biasing the voltage, I am already doing it. The problem is that I am trying to implement to different ranges permanently connected to MCU: 0-100mV (+/-50mV shifted by 50mV)  and 0-2V (+/-1V shifted by 1V). Depending on input voltage MCU will be controling multiplekser to switch between 2 different voltage references: 100mV and 2V. It is a bit uncommon design I guess but I want to try it, I just have to find solution to protect lower range input, possibly with resistors and Schottkey diode.

Comment: As an input, the source and sink currents are wrong parameter to look at. This rating is under injection current rating.

Comment: Right. I somehow thought it was output low connected to -3V. Yes, indeed. You're right.

Answer (score 2):

The input range to the STM32 is limited between Vcc and Vss-0.3V as you described, and in general I'd avoid applying signals less than Vss anyway.

What you need to do is offset the input voltage before feeding it to the ADC:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWWBxJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The first opamp buffers the input signal before feeding it to the summing amplifier. This takes a ±3.3V input and turns it into a 0-3.3V output suitable for the STM32's ADC. In this configuration, a 1.65V reading on the ADC means 0V on the input, so to get from the ADC reading back to the original voltage you just calculate \$V_{in} = 2(V_{ADC}-1.65)\$.